# To get list of printers assigned to a security group in AD using command line or WMI query (no powershell)

Tags: command-line, active-directory, wmi

I want to get the list of printers, user has access to. 
I managed to get list of security groups, user is the part of by using 'win32_GroupUser' WMI class. I am struggling now to get list printers assigned to a security group.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a solution for you, but you should know that Active Directory does not store information about printers assigned to groups and / or users.
You can check locally for every printer with the GetSecurityDescriptor () method of the Win32_Printer class if the user has not been blocked. If the user does not appear in SecurityDescriptor, it means that he has full access.

Printers can be assigned by GPO or login script.